# SQL: Take the last 4000 characters from text

Tags: sql, sql-server, datalength

I have a text column that I want to see if it has larger than 4000 characters.  If it does have more than 4000 characters, then start at the right most character and go back 4000 characters.

I realize that the following code is not correct. But it is a start.

```
select 
case 
when datalength(column1) > 4000 then
right(column1, 4000)
case datalength(column1) <= 4000 then 
column1
end 
from table_1
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for?

Comment: Just realized he was dealing with text and not varchar.  You cant use length

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219261/t-sql-selecting-top-n-characters-from-a-text-or-ntext-column

Comment: Ok fixed using datalength and substring.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN (DATALENGTH(column1) > 4000)
    THEN SUBSTRING(column1, DATALENGTH(test) - 3999, DATALENGTH(column1))
    ELSE column1
END
FROM table_1
```

Not fantastic, since you're recalculating DATALENGTH(column1) three times.

**EDIT**

Calculating only once using a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DATALENGTH(column1) AS LENGTH, column1 FROM table_1
)
SELECT CASE
    WHEN (LENGTH > 4000)
    THEN SUBSTRING(column1, LENGTH - 3999, LENGTH)
    ELSE column1
END
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Shouldn't be - if `DATALENGTH(test)` is 5000, should be going from 1001 to 5000.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Oracle. Here is the documentation on Substr: http://psoug.org/definition/SUBSTR.htm

```
select (case when length(column1) > 4000 
             then substr(column1, -4000) 
             else column1 
        end) 
from table_1;
```

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN datalength(MyColumn) > 4000 THEN SUBSTRING(REVERSE(MyColumn), 1, 4000) ELSE MyColumn END AS MyGenCol
```

Comment: OP is looking for RIGHT instead of LEFT.

Comment: I added `reverse`, this could get ugly...I don't like `TEXT` its deprecated.